# Not able to set multiple events in chaincode per transaction, getting only last event

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have applied multiple events in a function of a chaincode (Hyperledger Fabric v1.1).

```
func (t *SimpleChaincode) initUsers(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
...
//Event supplier_bare
err = stub.SetEvent("supplier_bare", userAsbytes)
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error(err.Error())
}
//Event supplier_bare_1
err = stub.SetEvent("supplier_bare_1", userAsbytes)
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error(err.Error())
}
...
return shim.Success(nil)
}
```

When I invoke the function, I only get the last event ('**supplier_bare_1**') per transaction.

Transaction (events):

```
...
 "events": {
            "chaincode_id": "mycc10",
            "tx_id":"5421ae37d6e1947b7121f411d64dc215ccacbe45b2d0a9c796cc4a3715c922d6",
            "event_name": "supplier_bare_1",
            "payload": {
                        "type": "Buffer",
                        "data": [
                                 ...
                                ]
                       }
           },
...
```

Does the chaincode works this way or there is a different approach to achieve multiple events in a single function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the shim code, there is only one slot in the shim for a chaincode event, so only the last call to setEvent will take effect.

Comment: Thanks, there was similar response for the similar question : https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-node?msg=q4jWWGmci6LLGRt8G

Answer (score 0):

Only one event is allowed per transaction execution. In case of multiple invocations to this method, only the last one will be recorded in the transaction execution record, and therefore raised to the application clients, listening the channel events.